# Is $ f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ via $ \ f(x) = x^{5} -3$ surjective?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory

Question:

Is $ f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ via  $ \ f(x) = x^{5} -3$ surjective?

My attempt:

No. Consider $ y = 2$. There doesn't exist $ x \in \mathbb{Q} \ such \ that \ y = f(x)$.

Am I correct? Is this the right approach to prove a function is not surjective?

Comment: Well, that is correct but I'd say it was incomplete.  How do you know that there is no $x\in \mathbb Q$ such that $x^5-3=2$?  That is true, but it deserves a proof.

Comment: That's the right approach. You might want to verify that that number isn't rational though.

Comment: It would imply $ x = 5^{1/5}$ which is not rational. Is that correct?

Comment: That's circular. I mean, that's the thing you are trying to prove.

Comment: Suppose $\big(\frac ab\big)^5=5$, $a,b$ without a common divisor. Then $a^5=5b^5$.  Then $5$ divides the RHS so it divides the LHS so $5$ divides $a$.  So $5^5$ divides the LHS.  So $5^5$ divides the RHS.  So $5$ divides $b$.  But then $5$ divides both $a$ and $b$ a contradiction.

Comment: You can try $y=-1$ and apply Fermat's Last Theorem

Comment: Interesting corollary: There is no IVT  for Rationals; maybe that is why we do Calculus on  Reals instead.

Comment: It is the right  approach: It suffices to exhibit just one $y\in \mathbb Q$ such that $x^5-3=y$ has no solution $x\in \mathbb Q. $  Instead of $y=2$ you could also take $y=0.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists no $\theta \in \Bbb Q$ such that

$f(\theta) = 0; \tag{1}$

if there were, then

$\theta^5 = 3; \tag{2}$

but

$\sqrt[5] \theta \notin \Bbb Q. \tag{3}$

To really finish things off, (3) should be proved:

If there *were* integers $r$, $s$ with $\gcd(r, s) = 1$ and

$\left (\dfrac{r}{s} \right )^5 = 3, \tag{4}$

then

$r^5 = 3s^5, \tag{5}$

so $3\mid r^5$, whence $3 \mid r$, whence

$r = 3t, \tag{6}$

so

$r^5 = 3^5 t^5,\tag{7}$

yielding

$3^5t^5 = 3s^5, \tag{8}$

whence

$3^4 t^5 = s^5, \tag{9}$

so $3 \mid s^5$, hence $3 \mid s$, contradicting $\gcd(r, s) = 1$.

This demonstration obviously parallels the classic proof that $\sqrt 2 \notin \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Probably: $\sqrt[5] 3 \notin \mathbb Q$? :)

Comment: @user251257:  probably so!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Doesn't the result for $\sqrt2$ generalize here? $a^{1/n}$ is Rational iff a is an n-th power of an integer?

Comment: @gary:  yes.  Vastly.

Comment: Since like a daunting general proof, specially since I stopped doing Math , and having last done Topology.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the "reduced form of a fraction" argument, you could apply [eisenstein's criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), where $p=5$, divides $5$, while $p^2$ does not divide $5$.

From this, we see that $x^5-5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, so none of the solutions $x^5=5$ are rational.

Comment: Yes, you can instead descend to Eisenstein!  Cheers!

Comment: @robert No offense meant! Only that the usual argument is lengthy, and there are other options available. I will reword statement.

Comment: None taken, though the road to Eisenstein from first principles has its own length!  Again I say, Cheers!

Comment: I like Eisenstein's criterion and laud its use, but I can never seem to remember it!

Comment: Indeed :). We can chat about it next time I see you at that coffee shop haha. Cheers

Comment: @RobertLewis: It takes an Einst...., er I mean, an Eisenstein to remember it!

Answer (score 1):

For yet another take on the non-surjectivity, consider the value $y = -1 \iff x^5-2=0\,$. The latter is a polynomial equation with integer coefficients, so by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) the only potential rational roots could be $\pm1, \pm2\,$. It can be easily verified by inspection that none of those is actually a root, so $x^5-2=0$ has no rational roots, and therefore $-1 \not \in f(\mathbb{Q})\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\big(\frac ab\big)^5=5$, $a,b$ without a common divisor. Then $a^5=5b^5$.  Then $5$ divides the RHS so it divides the LHS so $5$ divides $a$.  So $5^5$ divides the LHS.  So $5^5$ divides the RHS.  So $5$ divides $b$.  But then $5$ divides both $a$ and $b$ a contradiction.